# Alternative meanings of "la surveille"

Tags: noms, mots-composés

I am studying baptism records from province Québec that commonly used the phrase "née la veille".

In one record, there is a variation that clearly says, "née la surveille".  It seems specific, but I don't know what it means.  Is this "la surveille" different from "la veille" and "surveiller"?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/surveille

Comment: The term is now outdated and mostly used in vital records, it seems it survived longer in Québec than in France. You can also visit [that link](https://www.genealogy.com/forum/regional/countries/topics/canada/quebec/9000/) but it should **not**  "be written as "sur la veille"" as suggested in that question. [Etymology](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surveille) is *sorveille*, one word, *sor* being Old French for *sur*.

Comment: Notice that, if "surveille" (vs. "veille") is outdated, "surlendemain" (vs. "lendemain") is still in use!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Surveille* is an outdated word that means *avant-veille*. It comes form Old French [*sorveille*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surveille) (*sor* being Old French for *sur*) that can be traced back to the 12th century. [*Avant-veille*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avant-veille) is a more recent word that dates from the 16th century, the two words coexisted for a few centuries,  *avant-veille* gradually replacing *surveille* until the 20th century when *surveille* is mentioned as outdated.
This is quite clear when we look at the *Dictionnaire de l'Académie*, [the first edition, 1694,](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1V0035-08) has both words on equal terms and it is only in the [8th edition, 1935,](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8S2033) that *surveille* is stated as *peu usité* ("not much used"). Nowadays I expect *surveille* has disappeared from most basic dictionaries<sup>*</sup>.

We find the word mostly in old vital records in such phrases as *né(e)/mort(e) la surveille*. From looking at genealogy websites it seems that it survived longer in Québec than in France, but it might just be an impression.

- A [Canadian forum](https://www.genealogy.com/forum/regional/countries/topics/canada/quebec/9000/) where someone asks for the meaning of *surveille*.
- *Né la surveille* and *née l'avant-veille* appearing in extracts from the civil register for respectively husband and wife and reproduced in [a family tree](https://www.nosorigines.qc.ca/GenealogieQuebec.aspx?genealogie=Maurice_Arthur&pid=667512) of a Québec family.

<sub><sup>*</sup> For instance online editions of *Le Robert* and *Larousse* don't mention it.</sub>

Comment: Excellent work.  Yes, my French-English dictionary is missing this word and your answer is superior to many online sources.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, 2 days ago? "La veille" = 1 day ago, "la surveille" = 2 days ago?

Answer (score 3):

This "surveille" has nothing to do with "surveiller", as the Wiktionary link provided in the comment makes clear.

My guess would be that:

1. You're looking at older records and the term was more prevalent in that region at the time, or
2. Whoever wrote the records picked it because it's shorter to write than "l'avant-veille".

Or maybe a little bit of both!